# What kind of wood is this

Tags: wood

What kind of wood is this? It is made of a patchwork of wood pieces.

[image]

Comment: What is the size of what we are looking at?  width? thickness?  photo is kind of blurry

Answer (score 1):

From the worktops I have seen that is likely to be beech.

Upside is the surface is less likely to warp over time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like finger-jointed and edge-laminated pine. If you look at the edge you can probably see the characteristic zigzag cut pattern.

It's commonly used for "paint grade" millwork such as closet shelf cleat. It's cheaper and more stable than clear pine, but you may see the grain variation through light paint coatings. Try to avoid making any end cuts directly through the joints.

Comment: Those flecks look more like beech to me than pine.

Comment: They look like dirt or mold to me. Oh, for properly focused photos. :)